# If the test agency send the scores today, how long does it take for university to receive it electronically?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, language-exams

I have already received IELTS test score report form.

If the test agency send the scores today, how long does it take for university to receive it electronically?
I am applying into the PhD program,USA.

Answer (score 3):

If it is sent electronically, receipt will be measured in seconds or less. But that doesn't mean it will be noticed or quickly acted upon by a human. That is especially true at the moment as most universities are on break at the moment with (at best) reduced staff. Less than a week for any action would be fortunate. When people get back to work there will be a backlog and some tasks are more pressing than others.